# Traditional or Vintage mapping theme in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling

Is there a labeling or theme extension that can be downloaded for ArcMap that would help to make my maps look Vintage like historic maps?

I've looked at some of the Esri extensions and basemaps online, but there are so many I wouldn't really know where to start. I was hoping to zero in on one that someone had utilized and would recommend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My original answer is below the horizontal rule. All links are broken. Here is a link to an ArcGIS Pro style which includes several antique or historical styles or tools: [Historical Map Effects](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=228b671f0c964ede9b4a3edf7eaf8a7b)

It was inspired by an article written by the same people who would have answered on Ask a Cartographer. The article, "Achieving Historical Map Effects using Modern GIS" is available in a prepress version on [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/272180897_Achieving_Historical_Map_Effects_with_Modern_GIS).

Here's a [blog post by Wes Jones](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/mapping/historical-map-effects-torn-and-creased-parchment/) showing how to make "torn" parchment edges and [another one](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/mapping/historical-map-effects-waterways/) on how to give waterways an older look.

The CartoTalk website shut down several years ago and doesn't seem to have been archived anywhere.

---

Similar questions have been asked on the forums and "Ask a Cartographer". The question, [How can I give my map an "antique" feel?](http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.answers&q=1) has a link to a historical style (the 2nd link isn't working).

There's also a presentation from NACIS 2006, on Historical Map Effects. The link is [here](http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=resources.presentationsOlder). Scroll down the page or search for Historical.

There should also be some discussion, probably not ArcGIS-specific, on [CartoTalk](http://www.cartotalk.com).